# Cocoa app Create transparent view on top of all mac running applications

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am working on a mac osx application using Xcode. I would like to add a transparent full-screen view/window on top of all applications. So that I could 'draw' on the transparent view, and behind it will be whatever application, safari, word...etc.

I tried like the following

```
 NSRect rect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];   //this is full screen size, but still with the status bar like time, battery, etc.

 NSWindow *overlayWindow = [[NSWindow alloc]initWithContentRect:rect
 styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
 defer:NO];
 overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
 [self.window addChildWindow:overlayWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

It's a new full-screen child window of my mac-application. But it's not on top of all applications i am running on my mac.

So my question, 
How to add the view on top of my mac screen view(not only the top view of my application). 
Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 11):

See Apple's [FunkyOverlayWindow sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/Introduction/Intro.html).  In addition to setting the window's level, you will need to set its background color to clear and set it to non-opaque.  If it's transparent but you still want it to receive mouse events for drawing (rather than letting them pass through to the windows behind it), you'll need to do `[window setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO]`.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like what you want.

`NSWindow` has `- (void)setLevel:(NSInteger)windowLevel`

With this useful predefined levels. Pick one you like. Add or subtract 1 if you want it just above or just below one of these levels.

```
#define NSNormalWindowLevel          kCGNormalWindowLevel
#define NSFloatingWindowLevel        kCGFloatingWindowLevel
#define NSSubmenuWindowLevel         kCGTornOffMenuWindowLevel
#define NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel     kCGTornOffMenuWindowLevel
#define NSMainMenuWindowLevel        kCGMainMenuWindowLevel
#define NSStatusWindowLevel          kCGStatusWindowLevel
#define NSModalPanelWindowLevel      kCGModalPanelWindowLevel
#define NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel       kCGPopUpMenuWindowLevel
#define NSScreenSaverWindowLevel     kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel
#define NSDockWindowLevel            kCGDockWindowLevel
```

Comment: I am just thinking, setLevel here is to set the transparent window level "only" in the current application I programmed. Is that right ? If I call the others like safari, safari page will be on the top of my transparent window. In my mind, the transparent level should always be there no matter what other softwares I opened.

Comment: No, it'll stay in front of other apps provided you give it a high enough level.

Comment: I've finally made it work. It was because my NSWindow was modal.